# select Image from gallery and show in an ImageView?

Tags: android

i am developing an application which requires the user to select a photo from the gallery and set it as the profile picture. Now the below code is working properly on most of the devices( i have checked on Motorola Moto G, One plus X, MI 4i and some other). whenever i run it on redmi prime it is giving an error stated below:

Stacktrace

> Process: com.example.lordvoldemort.imagepicker, PID: 23291
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160807_003845_HDR.jpg
>   typ=image/jpeg }} to activity
>   {com.example.lordvoldemort.imagepicker/com.example.lordvoldemort.imagepicker.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3595)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3638)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:154)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
>                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface
>   method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                                  at
>   com.example.lordvoldemort.imagepicker.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:104)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6241)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3591)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3638) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:154) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290) 
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)

the code i am using on ActivityResult-

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null,
                                    null, null);
                    assert cursor != null;
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    newbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    ImageView ivImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
                    ivImage.setImageBitmap(newbitmap);


 public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            res = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return res;
    }
```

the error is -
Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference

Comment: did u get solution? same error facing

Answer (score 0):

> Now the below code is working properly on most of the devices

I suspect that it will work reliably on very few devices. It would depend a bit on where the `Uri` is coming from.

> the error is - Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference

That is because `MediaStore` does not recognize the `Uri`. Your `getPathFromURI()` will work for few `Uri` values on few devices (though, again, it depends a bit on where the `Uri` is coming from).

[A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). There is no requirement for there to be any "real path" for a `Uri`, any more than there has to be a file on the `stackoverflow.com` Web server at the path `/questions/39355114/select-image-from-gallery-and-show-in-an-imageview` (which is the path portion of the URL for this question).

Comment: so how do big firm like Whataspp or facebook doing on the exact same device?? there must be something lacking in my code

Comment: @AmanVerma: "so how do big firm like Whataspp or facebook doing on the exact same device?" -- most likely, they [use the `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html). For example, most image-loading libraries, like Picasso, know how to work with a `Uri`. In your case, you might need to make a local copy of the image, if you intend to work with it for a long time, as [your access rights to the content identified by the `Uri` are limited](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: On Android 4.4+, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, via [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html), and then use `takePersistableUriPermissions()`, to have long-term access to the content. You still get a `Uri`, and you still use that `Uri` with an image-loading library or manually using a `ContentResolver`.